# How to find minimum and maximum of function?

Tags: calculus, functions

> Given: the function $$f\left(x,y\right)=4x^{2} +3y^{2} -5x$$
>
> Find the $x$ values of the minimum and of the maximum on the set: $$
> \left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb R ^{2}: x^{2}+y^{2}=9 \right\} .$$

How can I do this?

I calculated the first and second derivatives but I don't know what to do with this set?

The solutions are: $\frac{83}{4} $ and $51$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 2):

Since $y^2=9-x^2$ on the set $S=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=9\}$, your function is
$$f(x,y)=4x^2+3(9-x^2)-5x=x^2-5x+27,\quad\text{on $S$}.$$
Now you just have to find the maximum and minimum of the quadratic
$$x^2-5x+27,$$
for $-3\leq x\leq3$.

(We have to restrict to $-3\leq x\leq3$ since otherwise there are no $y$ such that $(x,y)\in S$.)

Answer (score 0):

$$4x^2+3y^2-5x=4x^2+3(9-x^2)-5x=27+x^2-5x$$

$$=27+\left(x-\dfrac52\right)^2-\left(\dfrac52\right)^2\ge27-\left(\dfrac52\right)^2$$